# Use F keys as standard function keys for some apps on 2021 Macbook Pros

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

On Touchbar models, it's possible to configure the laptop's keyboard to use F keys as standard function keys only for some apps, and for all others - use "special features" as standard instead. This can be done, in mentioned models, by going to **Settings** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts**.

The problem is I can't seem to figure out how to configure this on 2021+ Macbook 14"/16" models which don't have a Touchbar anymore.

Any ideas or solutions?

Answer (score 0):

As of May 2023 on **Mac OS Ventura (13.4)**, **MacBook Pro 14-inch 2021** model, you go to

**System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Function Keys**

and activate the option "Use F1, F2 etc. keys as standard function keys"

Afterwards, you can use the <kbd>fn</kbd> key to toggle back to the brightness, volume, etc., key behaviour.